# Expected view ShowImageList to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am getting below issue while accessing the urls /show_image/, /products/, /categories/. But show_image/(?P[\w-]+)/$ url is working fine

```
Expected view ShowImageList to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.
```

My urls.py is

```
url(r'^products',ProductList.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name="product-list"),
url(r'^show_image/$', ShowImageList.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name='ShowImage'),
url(r'^show_image/(?P<pk>[\w-]+)/$', ShowImageDetail.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name='image_detail'),
url(r'^categories/', Categories.as_view({'get': 'retrieve'}), name= 'categories'),
```

My views.py is

```
class ShowImageList(ResponseModelViewSet):
    queryset = ProductImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShowImageSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        file = request.data['original']
        product = request.data['product']
        caption = request.data['caption']
        display_order = request.data['display_order']
        p = Product.objects.get(pk=product)
        ProductImage.objects.create(product=p, original=file, caption=caption, display_order=display_order)
        return Response(json.dumps({'message': "Uploaded"}))

class ShowImageDetail(ResponseModelViewSet):
    queryset = ProductImage.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ShowImageSerializer


class ProductList(ResponseModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ProductLinkSerializer
    model=Product
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Product.objects.all()
```

I am facing error same error every urls except /show_image/(?P[\w-]+)/$

Comment: You need to show us your view

Comment: Please share the `ShowImageDetail` implementation.

Comment: I have added view.py

Comment: What is `ResponseModelViewSet`?

Comment: Hi, I am unable to add whole code here so please refer http://notes.io/8kwz